# Ubuntu AWS ec2 NodeJS port is already in use

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I know this question has been asked many times on SO and I'm truly at a loss for what I'm doing wrong been trying to diagnose this issue for 6 hours now.

I'm using an AWS EC2 instance with NodeJS installed on it and I'm simply trying to start my back-end server. Whenever I run node it's telling me that the address is already in use.

Nginx Server Configuration:

[image]

Error I'm getting when I run node on my node server file:

[image]

What I've tried:

1. I've tried running `sudo lsof -i tcp:5000` which lists out the ports that are running and it lists out the PID, which I then run `sudo kill -9 17048` or whatever the PID is that runs on that port and tried rerunning node and it still says the address is in use and I run the command again and it's a different PID.
2. I've already went into my security groups on my aws instance and opened the TCP port 5000 to `0.0.0.0/0` which is the back-end.
3. I'm not sure if this matters but I'm using nginx and my nginx default configuration is pointed to port 5000
4. I tried changing the port based on other SO suggestions in my node server and rerunning it and it gives me the same error of eaddressinuse but with the new port I changed.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong I think I'm missing something very small but I'm not sure what.

Here is my node server code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
var fs = require("fs");
const router = express.Router();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const config = dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "../config/.env") });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "/../build/index.html");

const app = express();

var Blog = require("../routes/Blog");
var Schedule = require("../routes/Schedule");
var detailedReport = require("../routes/detailedReport");
var Login = require("../routes/Login");
var Admin = require("../routes/Admin");
var Forms = require("../routes/Forms");

app.use(cors());
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

// GET/POST Requests
app.use("/api", Blog);
app.use("/api", Schedule);
app.use("/api", detailedReport);
app.use("/api", Login);
app.use("/api", Admin);
app.use("/api", Forms);

// Serve static files on server
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));

app.get("*.js", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + ".gz";
  res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
  next();
});
app.get("*.css", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + ".gz";
  res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/css");
  next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server successfully started`);
});
```

Comment: Idk if it matters but I just found out when I kill the PID process for that port and run to see if any ports are open it comes up with a new PID even though I deleted it odd.

Comment: Well, what is that pid? Have you checked what executable is responsible for opening that port? Are you running pm2, or a Node.js process via systemd?

Comment: I think I just fixed it. I had to kill nodejs process entirely, restart it and clear all ports for 5000 and now im not getting the eaddressinuse error anymore